# How can I grow ivy (or a bush or other plant) in my fireplace that is low-maintenance and bug-repellant?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, plant-recommendations

I've never gardened, but I do love design.  I'm moving into a new place that has an unusable fireplace, and I think it'd look amazing if it had a green, leafy plant filling the interior of it.  Since I've never gardened, I think one that is robust and requires little light and minimal maintenance, especially when it comes to bugs, is best.  Bonus points if it's a plant that is good for air quality as well.  Any ideas?  How should I go about it?

Preliminary research suggests philodendron or grape ivy: are these good ideas?  How long will they take to grow to fill a fireplace?  (I imagine the philodendron would grow up from the base, while I'd have to build a pot for the grape ivy and then it would hang down).

Comment: How much natural light will the fireplace get?

Comment: Is this fireplace inside the house or out in the garden? Your mention of garden design sort of hints that it's outside...

Comment: It is inside, with low-medium shaded light. Open to supplementing the amount of light somehow.

Answer (score 3):

English Ivy might be an option for you since you are concerned about air quality.  English Ivy removes formaldehyde and many other chemicals from the air.  Its leaves are poisonous, however, so if you have house pets that may be a problem.  It may need supplemental light.

Grape Ivy is another good option.